# Collection of functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $F$ be the collection of all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $F$ is uncountable.

Proof:
Let $r \in \mathbb{R} $. Then the function $f: x \to x^r$ is in $F$. Since the reals themselves are uncountable, we have uncountably many functions of the type $x^r$.

I'm unsure wether my argument is viable. What do you think?

Comment: Simpler:  just use constant functions.

Comment: It's a good idea. Unfortunately you chose $f$ which aren't actually defined everywhere (what is $f_r(-1)$?) but it's the right idea. Even more simply consider the constant functions

Comment: Somehow I didn't come up with the easiest approach. Thanks!

Comment: If one knows that the collection of all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$ is already uncountable, then one can argue that your collection of real function cannot be smaller. But of course if what one knows in advance is that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, then a method like yours is natural.

Comment: Also, $f_{r}(0)$ is undefined when $r<0.$

Comment: You can use a technique similar to diagonalization. Assume that the set of all real valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ is countable; list them $\{f_1,f_2,f_3,\dots\}$. Construct a new function $f$ that differs from each $f_i$ at at least one point for each $i$. Reach a contradiction.